# Is it possible to install Greenplum database on Mac?

Tags: greenplum

Is it possible to install Greenplum on Mac. I can only see database servers for SuSE and RedHat linux on [this page](https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gpdb).
I am having trouble to get started.Though i have tried sandbox VM, that works fine.

Comment: They used to have a Mac distribution as trial but some time ago it disappeared off network.pivotal.io.

What error are you getting?

Also, you may want to check the opensource version:  https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb and maybe could build it on the Mac?

Comment: Thank you , Its not about error, though i get  "Installer will only install on SuSE x86_64" when i try SuSE version or same for RedHat. On official documentation there are certain steps mentioned under topic " Mac OS X System Settings",  http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/prep_os-system-params.html#topic6.  I am not sure what does this mean

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum is not bundled for Mac as a Pivotal distribution. Many developers, though, build and test Greenplum on Macs and most of the development stations used at Pivotal are Macs.

If the [build instructions](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb) do not work for you there is a [wiki page for building on that environment](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/wiki/How-to-build-on-OSX).

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it is necessary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.